# Sidebar next to CMS block on category page

Tags: magento2, cms-block, category-view

I'm somewhat new to **Magento 2** but most of it is going just fine. There is a minor issue I'm experiencing and I can't seem to figure out how I can fix this.

I've added a **CMS block** to a category containing information about that category.
Then I've added a sidebar content trough Layout Update XML.

All this works fine, but the one problem is that the the sidebar pops under the content of the page. And I just want it to stick to the right like a sidebar should.

I'm probably missing something in the Layout Update XML for this not happening.

Any thoughts on how I would be able to fix this?